# SparkSQL: HQL script in file to be loaded on Python code

Tags: python, apache-spark, hql, pyspark

Normally, literal query strings suffices for short statements, like these:

```
count = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM db.table").count()
```

However, there are cases where I have a lengthy Hive query script, and that would be too cumbersome to place in Python code.

How do I go about referencing an HQL file and get it executed in Python-SparkSQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
count = sqlContext.sql(open("file.hql").read()).count()
```

Comment: What fix can be applied to run this in cluster mode? Since open doesn't work in cluster.

Answer (score 0):

### From spark-sql , I can do this one, (didnt tested from python)

I see in the spark2 versions it worked with “-f” option:

Ex:
hsql script:
test.sql

select * from tpcds_text_2.income_band LIMIT 5;

Spark-sql:

```
/usr/odp/3.2.2.0-1/spark2/bin/spark-sql -f /tmp/hive-testbench-hdp3/test.sql
```

Results:
Apart from reguler logging resuls also shown here

```
1 0     10000
2 10001 20000
3 20001 30000
4 30001 40000
5 40001 50000
```

Time taken: 14.214 seconds, Fetched 5 row(s)

Answer (score 0):

one more way to run the hql/sql  from spark is using the below way

logging into spark-sql

```
spark-sql>
```

Followed by followed by source the hql/sql fiels

```
spark-sql> source /tmp/hive-testbench-hdp3/test.sql;
```

able to get the same results

```
23/09/27 16:29:28 INFO YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
23/09/27 16:29:28 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (processCmd at CliDriver.java:376) finished in 4.773 s
23/09/27 16:29:28 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: processCmd at CliDriver.java:376, took 4.919867 s
23/09/27 16:29:29 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on manish2.odp.ce:37803 in memory (size: 4.6 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
1   0   10000
2   10001   20000
3   20001   30000
4   30001   40000
5   40001   50000
Time taken: 8.544 seconds, Fetched 5 row(s)
23/09/27 16:29:29 INFO SparkSQLCLIDriver: Time taken: 8.544 seconds, Fetched 5 row(s)
23/09/27 16:29:29 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on manish1.odp.ce:35619 in memory (size: 4.6 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
23/09/27 16:29:29 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2 stored as values in memory (estimated size 434.7 KB, free 365.4 MB)
```